# Error while deploying custom settings metadata to 'Enterprise' org - Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am getting below error while deploying a protected custom settings to enterprise org, which is on Spring'20 release.

```
Custom Object You can't set the visibility for a Custom Setting to Protected unless you are in a developer or scratch org.
```

Looks like below release update has impacted the deployment of custom settings,
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_custom_settings_org_visibility.htm

Has anybody faced this issue and know how it can be handled? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to set the visibility for a custom setting in a production org. Visibility settings are only for managed packages to provide a way for package developers to control the exposure outside of the package. This allows storing sensitive data visible for the package only.

For your production org custom setting reading and writing should be set with [permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_grant_permission.htm&type=5).

> Visibility—(Only available in developer or scratch orgs) Select the visibility. After you save a custom setting, you cannot change this value.
>
> Protected—If the custom setting is contained in a managed package, subscribing organizations can't see the custom setting—it doesn't display as part of the package list. In addition, subscribing organizations can't access the custom setting using Apex or the API. Custom settings can only be accessed by the Apex code that is part of the managed package. If the custom setting is contained in an unmanaged package, the custom setting is available through the Enterprise WSDL like any custom object (as if the Visibility was Public.)
>
> Public—The custom setting is available through the Enterprise WSDL like any custom object. You can package custom settings defined as public. The subscribing organizations can edit the values, and access them using Apex and SOAP API, regardless of the type of package (managed or unmanaged).

[Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_define.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks Gerard! I have started to face this deployment issue only in orgs which are on Spring'20 release. Earlier deployment was working fine for same custom setting with 'protected' visibility in Enterprise edition orgs. Is it safe to say that after 'Visibility' related change in Spring'20 release this has impacted?

Comment: I think that too.